# Unable to connect to WiFi Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: wireless, 15.10

I am new here and new with Ubuntu. I have version 15.10, connected to my macbook pro retina. I am trying to get wifi to work, but no networks are detected on my computer, so I am using an ethernet cable. I'm sure there are some drivers I am supposed to download, but I can not find them. Can someone help me find the drivers I need or help me otherwise?
I can not use a different version of Ubuntu, because the program I need to run is specifically for 15.10. My computer has a BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Ada. pter

Comment: Possibly related to this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1508719 -- the last comment there indicates it may have been fixed in Ubuntu 16.04 :| What's the program that only runs on 15.10? Maybe there's a way to get it to work on 16.04

Comment: Have you tried the first answer on this question (installing `bcmwl-kernel-source` package and then `modprobe wl`) http://askubuntu.com/questions/592555/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers-for-chip-id-bcm4360-pci-id-14e443a0

Comment: So I had to redo my unstallation, and this time I am running jnto a problem. At first this fixed worked, but than I had to restart my computerband lost all of the work I did on the current installation. The first thing I needed to do to get back to where I was was to fix the wifi again. But now when I ejter the command sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source, I get the error "unable to find the package bcmwl-kernel-source". Any idea what I should do, or do I need to start all over and reinstall ubuntu again?