# Error: cannot find a GRUB drive

Tags: boot, grub2

I previously posted here with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787554/unable-to-connect-to-wifi-ubuntu-15-10) question, which is now resolved. I am trying to install ubuntu 15.10 on my macbook pro with a flash drive. Specifically, I am following [these](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs171/materials/pdfs/How_to_Dual-Boot_OSX_and_Ubuntu.pdf) instructions I found by searching, however I did not follow Part 1 of this guide since I am using a flash drive that my friend put Ubuntu onto already. I hope this is not related to the problem that I am having now.

I am now up to part 4: making Ubuntu bootable. I am up to the step where I have to type into terminal:

```
grub-mkconfig -o boot/grub/grub.cfg
And this is the results that I get:
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-16-generic
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdc1.  Check your device.map. 
done
```

---

When I use

```
cat /boot/grub/device.map
```

(which I found in a similar forum post)

All I get is:

```
(hd0)   /dev/disk/by-id/ata-APPLE_SSD_SM0256F_S1K4NYAFC30996

(hd1)   /dev/disk/by-id/usb-SanDisk_Cruzer_4C531001431122101253-0:0
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

sudo fdisk -1 gives me:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu
Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/loop0: 1.1 GiB, 1130688512 bytes, 2208376 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 233.8 GiB, 251000193024 bytes, 490234752 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: BD61344F-612D-4DB6-9691-47475BB7DFE3

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1         40    409639    409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sda2     409640 425544751 425135112 202.7G Apple Core storage
/dev/sda3  425544752 426814287   1269536 619.9M Apple boot
/dev/sda4  426814288 431791719   4977432   2.4G Apple HFS/HFS+
/dev/sda5  431792128 447791103  15998976   7.6G Linux swap
/dev/sda6  447791104 490233855  42442752  20.2G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdc: 29.8 GiB, 32015679488 bytes, 62530624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x429817b4

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *          0 2301535 2301536  1.1G  0 Empty
/dev/sdc2       2279532 2284075    4544  2.2M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
root@ubuntu:/#
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
root@ubuntu:/# cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt6'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=0
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 0 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt6'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-38-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-38-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-38-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-38-generic-advanced-e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.2.0-38-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-38-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-38-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-38-generic (upstart)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-38-generic-init-upstart-e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.2.0-38-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-38-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff init=/sbin/upstart
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-38-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-38-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-38-generic-recovery-e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.2.0-38-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-38-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-38-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-16-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-16-generic-advanced-e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.2.0-16-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-16-generic root=UUID=e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-16-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-16-generic (upstart)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-16-generic-init-upstart-e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.2.0-16-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-16-generic root=UUID=e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff init=/sbin/upstart
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-16-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-16-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-16-generic-recovery-e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.2.0-16-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-16-generic root=UUID=e3b2cb67-7623-4f39-a4e5-1b3082a03c02 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-16-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
root@ubuntu:/#
```

Answer (score 5):

This should be better as a comment but I still don't have permission for it. I'm an ex developer of GRUB.
What is probably happening is that grub-mkconfig fails to detect the modules necessary for you /dev/sdc1 . It is not a problem if you driver does not contais your /boot (where grub stores it modules) or the kernel files to boot.
Please share your /**boot/grub/grub.cfg** as well
Change the value of GRUB_TIMEOUT to 10

What is the output of `sudo fdisk -l` what is the filesystem in sdc1?
at grub prompt type c (to enter shell) and type `ls` what drivers it shows to you?

Comment: bash: /boot/grub.cfg: No such file or directory

Comment: I added my output to sudo fdisk -1 to my original post

Comment: A few questions: how to I change the value of GRUB_TIMEOUT? Wben you say "at grub prompt type c", how do I get to this grub prompt? Also, when you say "it is not a problem" do you mean that I might be able to just go on with the instructions and ignore this, or do you mean I can easily do something to fix it?

Comment: sorry it should be /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Comment: At the grub menu when the options show up you can type c to get to the prompt.
It is not a problem since it should boot normally since sdc1 wouldn't be needed to load kernel files

Comment: bash: /boot/grub/grub.cfg: Permission denied

Comment: `cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: Still not sure what you mean by grub menu. Is that something I have been to before? What command do I enter to get to it?

Comment: When you boot your machine GRUB you show you a menu to chose your options from but only if GRUB_TIMEOUT is not 0 in /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Comment: I added the results to cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg to my original post. How do I edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg?

Comment: you can put `set timeout=0` right after "### END /etc/grub.d/00_header" 
note that it will be overwritten after you run grub-mkconfig again

You can edit it using any editor you want `sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg` should work.

Probably grub will boot your machine without problem.
please post you grub.cfg in a gits its too verbose. gist.github.com    

you can put in a gist also the output of  `sudo mount` and `ls /boot`

Comment: Can you take a look at my most recent issue? I really appreciate all the help.http://askubuntu.com/questions/788295/trouble-booting-with-grub