# Trouble booting with Grub

Tags: grub2

everything was working fine and ubuntu was booting without a flash drive on my macbook pro, and now all of a sudden when I try to boot I get to this grub menu:https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux

I tried following the directions on this page, but right away I ran into a problem. When I type in "1s" to see my partitions, I get "error: can't find command `1s'.

I know it would probably be useful if I provided my grub version, but all I can tell you is "GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-29...". The rest is covered by a broken part on my screen, so if that is needed hopefully there is another way I could get that information.

Here is a previous question of mine, which might be relevent: [Error: cannot find a GRUB drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787762/error-cannot-find-a-grub-drive/787769?noredirect=1#comment1183041_787769)

Answer (score 0):

How did it stop working? Did you change any bios conf? Added removed or changed the order of any disks?
what the command `lsmod` gives? and `insmod normal`?
ls comes from a grub module usually at /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ls.mod (x86_64-efi depends on your arch).

When booting grub try to load the "normal" module and if it fails it will go to rescue (that is what happened to you).
Did it print any errors on boot?

Comment: I did go into system preferences in OSX and set the startup disk to "Macintosh HD". Could this be the problem?

Comment: Yes. Grub ia sensitiva to this kind of change. You may have charged how It sees the disks and because of that it can't read grub.cfg or load its modules anymore.

Comment: Ok, guess I screwed up. When I try to go back and change the startup disk to Ubuntu Boot Loader, it gives me the error "You can’t change the startup disk to the selected disk." "Building boot caches on boot helper partition failed." Is there something I can do or do I have to start all over?

Comment: You were booting from the correct disk since you could start grub but something was different than expected so I c grub is seeing disks in different order. You can have something like that enabling or disabling efi as well. It's hard to tell without any debug output. Maybe try other options for root "set root=hd(0,0)"  you can try different values 0,1 1,0 etc and try insmod normal

Comment: Ok, I am a little confused by your response (was something supposed to happen when I enter the command insmod normal? Because it gave no output.) so I think I will just start all over if you don't think theres a way I can access the debug. Is there a way to install ubuntu with grub so it isn't the default boot on my conputer though?

Comment: If you want we can chat at skype manoel_abranches 
' insmod normal' don' t give any output if it load correctly. You can check if it shows up with the command `lsmod`
If yes everything is ok with grub but it probably can' t find the grub.cfg at root. 
at this point `ls` should show the available partitions.
`echo $root` shows to you the current  content of the root variable.