# How to Setup Wireless Connection

Tags: wireless, internet

No computer background, recently booted ubuntu from a new desktop that did not have an OS installed. Would like someone's help on how to I can setup a wifi connection to the home internet...

Comment: this video can help you if you are using unity desktop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXUumcDzGBs

Comment: Hi Samer, thanks for responding man. What do you mean by unity desktop...

Comment: Also, I checked out that video but it was not helpful

Comment: Which Ubuntu version have you installed? Does the system in the video look familiar to you?

Comment: Yes, its ubuntu version 16.04 LTS

Comment: Here's [the official guide on that](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-connect.html).

Comment: I followed the steps. When I get to the step of installing additional drivers, I go to the appropriate location "Software and updates" and to additional drivers, but it says that no additional drivers are found. That is as far as the documentation goes, so i am not sure what to do.

Comment: Really need an individual's continued help...been sitting for many hours and no progress. Thank you.

Comment: What wireless  adapter does your system have?
Hint:  `lspci | grep -i wireless`
Ubuntu 16.04 has a lot of drivers already in its repository. If your computer is new, I would expect no additional drivers are necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply WillemK. I typed that code into the terminal..I have Broadcom BCM4360 802.11ac wireless network adapter rev03. Also, i currently am offline. So no internet access at all.

Comment: You can try what they suggest [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592555/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers-for-chip-id-bcm4360-pci-id-14e443a0). `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source` and `sudo modprobe wl`.

Comment: Thanks darksky. I've seen a lot of the online suggestions. I tried the piece of code you are suggesting, but it returns that it is unable to locate the package...not sure what that means.

Comment: Please try with a temporary working internet connection: `sudo apt-get update` and then: `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` and then reboot.

Comment: @F.Samain Try plugging your laptop/pc to internet via Ethernet cable so that you can install stuff.