# extract a tarball with vanilla Ubuntu

Tags: drivers

I've just installed the newest Ubuntu version on a 2015 mac book air, thanks to the bright engineers over at Apple, the wifi card doesn't work out the box and so I had to download the tar file from the developers website. However, I don't know how to install it. I have seen that you can execute a bunch of line in the command prompt along the lines of `./configure` and `make`, but those are programs that I have to install over the internet. I can't do this for obvious reasons (I don't have any means to access the interenet.)

Is there any solution you guys can suggest?

Thanks guys

Comment: Some suggestions here: [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline). However before going down that route you should probably ask a question about your wifi card specifically (there may already be a known solution that doesn't involve building drivers from source).

Comment: @steeldriver after looking around, installing the drivers from source seems to be the standard way of doing it. I could also buy a wifi dongle but that is anbnoying as you cna imagine

Answer (score 1):

`tar -zxf filename.tgz`

should do it

However, if the tarball contains sourcecode which you have to build I'm afraid you won't be able to avoid installing developer packages that will allow you to build the package from source.
Providing the link/driver you are talking about could shed some more light on what the problem is (maybe there are alternatives to install it).

Also: you can download the packages and copy over USB stick, and move them to your laptop and install them with `dpkg -i packagename.deb` so internet is not necessary, but very helpful.

Comment: -xzvf works but that only extracts it, the driver is the one for this device: https://www.broadcom.com/products/wireless/wireless-lan-infrastructure/bcm4360#overview

Comment: Can you please check this first?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/592555/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers-for-chip-id-bcm4360-pci-id-14e443a0