# How can I setup wifi without LAN cable interface?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I've installed ubuntu, I am trying to setup network.
My laptop doesn't have LAN interface, so I only have to connect internet with wifi.
But currently I couldn't setup wifi.

Below is my situation

```
joont> ifconfig
joont> 
lo flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK, RUNNING> mtu 65536
....
```

> only showing lo

```
joont> iwconfig
joont> 
no wireless extensions.
```

> Also only showing lo

```
joont> lshw -C network
joont>
*- network
  description: Network controller
  product: BCM4360 82.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
  vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries.
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@000:03:00.0
  version: 03
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33 MHz
  ....
```

> I can find  wifi network interface

As you can see from above, I currently only have loopback interface.

So.. what thing I have to do first?
Have to install wireless network driver? Or install another thing?
Can you help me?

Comment: Exactly which flavor of Ubuntu? And exactly which release?

Comment: 18.04 LTS @user535733

Comment: Well, maybe. I don't think the wireless NIC driver is installed. Because my uuuntu only shows the loopback interface.

Comment: How can I check it?

Comment: BCM4360 (old, 2016): https://askubuntu.com/questions/592555/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers-for-chip-id-bcm4360-pci-id-14e443a0. You do indeed have a real chicken-and-egg problem.

Comment: I solved by referring https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers. Thanks for your hints.

Comment: Thank you for telling us how you solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

If your device has Bluetooth, you can use tethering to connect to the internet via another device using Bluetooth.

1: Connect your device to a device with an internet connection via Bluetooth, such as a smartphone.

2: Click the tray in the top right of the screen and click the WiFi dropdown menu.

3: Connect to your Bluetooth device.

You should now be able to connect to the internet using Bluetooth tethering.

You may have to enable Bluetooth tethering on your internet connected device before following these steps.